# AngularFireMessagingModule and AngularFireStorageModule in AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, angularfire2

I'm a new baby with angular4, But it is said that angularfire2 is an official for implementation firebase using angular, but I can't see how to implement cloud messaging using the newest release 4.0.0-rc.0

i've try

```
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from 'angularfire2/storage';
import { AngularFireMessagingModule } from 'angularfire2/messaging';
```

but those modules doesn't exist

I have to implement fcm for my project, can anyone give me solution?
or perhaps could anyone tell me which angularfire2 version that support cloud messaging and some example maybe??

Any help will be appreciated. I you not capable to solve it, don't close on me please..

Comment: Have you even tried it with angular4?

Comment: i've already succeed create some experiment with AngularFireAuth and AngularFireDatabase, but cannot find any documentation using AngularFireMessaging. Or did you mean using NativeScript? Can you give me some link? thx

Comment: When you said "_I can't see how to implement cloud messaging using the newwest release 4.0.0-rc.0_" I thought you've already done it with a previous version.

Comment: nope, i'm from android background, did you? could you tell me which version that possible to do it? I want to implement it using typescript (above version 2)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like AngularFireStorageModule and AngularFireMessagingModule have not been released yet, and they are working on it. I would suggest that you just wait until it gets released.

[Picture from AngularFire2 Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBJCx.png)